# How can I get copied directory sizes using robocopy and copy to match?

Tags: windows-10, robocopy, windows-backup

I have been having trouble with the size of data on disk not being reported consistently the same. Robocopy log is ok but properties information gives different directory sizes. Recently I made a change where I keep my master directory on the internal hard drive and back up to an external hard drive.

I am using the following code (other directories are being copied as well but these are giving no discrepancy is file sizes):

```
Robocopy "C:\MM\mary"  "D:\mary" /E /NC /NFL /NS /NDL /NP /TEE /R:5 /W:15 /LOG+:Backup.log
Robocopy "C:\MM\med.2" "D:\med.2" /E /NC /NFL /NS /NDL /NP /TEE /R:5 /W:15 /LOG+:Backup.log
```

Windows 10 sees some jpg files as system files. I found this out when I deleted a directory on my hard drive. I have from time to time removed thumb files from external hard drive. Is there a way I can remove extraneous data when I do my backups (1-using Robocopy, 2-using copy command in windows 10)?

Is it important to keep the file structure when copying? What part of Robocopy is ensuring that? MIR did not give the best results so I resorted to the code seen above.

What is really confusing is that sometimes file size of the copied directory is smaller like 3 bytes smaller.

I use Robocopy for speed and ease of use.

MM

Comment: Are you saying there's an actual problem? Please use thr EDIT button to add context and details to help us understand what your situation is and what you're asking.

Comment: What does data corruption have to do with mis-association of file types? As far as setting file associations, the *assoc* command can set them, or use an application such as IrfanView to take that type. Se https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc

Comment: If you want to clear file from the destination use the mirror option or purge option.